# Closest RL Match for Fictional Helicopter Design?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

Erm, not sure if this is the best place to post this but it seems like the best place to get a pretty straight answer thus far in my search.

[image: Michi/Trixie's helicopter from Mach GoGoGo/Speed Racer 1966-1968]

So yeah, this helicopter is obviously from a cartoon – but I'm writing a story and I wanted to refer to it more specifically if possible, and also I'm just plain curious about what real rotorcraft(s) it was most likely based off of. And so far the entire rest of Google has not been much help. Plus, I've tried comparing some of the era models (i.e. ***1960s, 1966-1968***) I've found pics of on my own – but yeah, I am pretty clueless here. =(

Can anyone help? Thank you so very much for your time!

**EDIT:** I mentioned the year and I put the source in the pic description, but I'll reiterate both here. It's ***Michi/Trixie's helicopter from the Japanese anime Mach GoGoGo/Speed Racer 1966-1968***.

Comment: Might help if you told us the cartoon/comic and the year that the cartoon came out so we can compare aircraft of a similar era and maybe even region.

Comment: Edited with necessary info more clearly marked. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the [Bell 47J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_47J_Ranger):

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_47)</sup>

The Bell 47 was configurable with floats more in-line with the image originally posted, but I can't find a lot of images with the full skin frame and floats, but here is one:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Goodall Aircraft History](https://www.goodall.com.au/photographs/airliners-2/airliners2.html)</sup>

Comment: Aaaah, that looks incredibly similar, even down to the design in the first pic minus the colors! This _definitely_ works. OMG THANK YOU _SO_ MUCH ❤

Comment: Yeah that's it.  By the mid 60s it would have been the most recognized helicopter in the public's mind from TV and movies so I would have expected a cartoon to be a likeness of a '47 J.

Answer (score 0):

The bulbous design makes me think of the [MD500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD_Helicopters_MD_500), although the tail of that, like most helicopters, comes from the top of the body, while your cartoon image has the tail connecting at the bottom.

[image]